# Circle divided into six parts

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to divide the circle into six parts and between them, some spaces and each divided div's contains some text also. I have tried using `clip-path` but the problem is when I add some margin to achieve space between them it is not showing and due to absolute position all div's text come at the same position So, the code becomes mashup. [so far what I had tried](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/pXWyRG)  Is there any other better way to achieve this output. Can anyone suggest point me.
Desired output:
[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks you saved my time actually I had searched with different keyword.

Comment: Also you can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036195/create-svg-circle-using-path-with-6-segments/56039943#

Comment: @enxaneta I will try.